# how to get nearest location for point in openlayers OSM

Tags: openlayers, openstreetmap

Recently I have stared working with openlayers & openstreetmap.
What I want to do is draw a line & then get nearest locations of start point & end point from there longitude and latitude.
I am able to get longitude and latitude of point bellow is script of it.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var map, layer;
    function init(){
        var
        map = new OpenLayers.Map("map");
        layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM( "Simple OSM Map");

        // allow testing of specific renderers via "?renderer=Canvas", etc
        var renderer = OpenLayers.Util.getParameters(window.location.href).renderer;
        renderer = (renderer) ? [renderer]:OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.prototype.renderers;

        var vectors = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Vector Layer", {
            renderers: renderer
        });
        vectors.events.on({
            'featureselected': function(feature) {
                $('counter').innerHTML = this.selectedFeatures.length;
            },
            'featureunselected': function(feature) {
                $('counter').innerHTML = this.selectedFeatures.length;
            }
        });

        map.addLayers([layer, vectors]);

        line =  new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(
                vectors, OpenLayers.Handler.Path
           );

       line.events.register('featureadded', line, handleMapClick);

        map.addControl(line);

         map.setCenter(
            new OpenLayers.LonLat(-71.147, 42.472).transform(
                new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                map.getProjectionObject()
            ), 15
        ); 
    }

  function handleMapClick(evt)
  {
  // create a WKT reader/parser/writer          
  var wkt = new OpenLayers.Format.WKT();

   // write out the feature's geometry in WKT format
   var out = wkt.write(evt.feature);
   alert(out);
  }
```

But I am not able to get its nearest location.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Overpass_API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) to get all Locations in the BBox of the line (you can buffer that).
If your line is too long for that you can buffer (with OL) the line and use "By polygon"-selection
now you have a (hopefully) small set to get the nearest.